# Exporting Markdown + CSS to PDF

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I'm in need of an application that can do something like [Marked for OS X](http://markedapp.com) does.

The function I need is a bit more specific: I want the app to export Markdown to PDF, **but using CSS** - I've achieved this using BBEdit (using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css" />` and exporting, and with Marked, I can just select the CSS file.

I'm using ReText for Markdown editing, but said method doesn't work - the PDF exportation is posible, but without styling.

Any way to achieve this? I don't mind using the Terminal or any library lying around - if I can achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReText 4.0, recently released, now supports styles (and they are correctly exported to PDF too).

For example, if file you are editing is `somefile.mkd`, create a stylesheet named `somefile.css` in the same folder, and that style will be automatically loaded.

Comment: +1 for retext, great work on it Dmitry! I haven't seen the 4.0 version on launchpad yet though. Your PPA only has 3.1.3 in it.

Comment: THIS! <3 I should look for it, though — haven't seen the 4.0 either.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which you can get by installing the Ubuntu package of the same name ([wkhtmltopdf](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wkhtmltopdf) [image: Install wkhtmltopdf]).

Answer (score 0):

You can use python markdown (from the python-markdown package) and [xhtml2pdf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xhtml2pdf.1.html) (from the python-pisa package).

You could have a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

CSS_FILE=~/path/to/style.css

MARKDOWN_FILE=$1.mkd
HTML_FILE=$1.html
PDF_FILE=$1.pdf

markdown_py $MARKDOWN_FILE > $HTML_FILE
xhtml2pdf --quiet --css $CSS_FILE $HTML_FILE $PDF_FILE
rm $HTML_FILE
```

Put the above code in mkd2pdf, make the file executable (`chmod +x mkd2pdf`).

Say your markdown file is called `file.mkd` then you could run

```
./mkd2pdf file
```

and you would have file.pdf generated in the same directory. (Note the lack of a suffix in the above line).

Comment: Sigh: `CSSParseError: Selector Pseudo Function closing ')' not found:: (u':not(', u'[controls]){display:')
*** ERRORS OCCURED` when parsing the Minified Bootstrap CSS file. Any way to fail silently or something? This seems like to be the answer.

Comment: @AeroCross - I've updated the script to add the `--quiet` flag which should suppress the output.

Comment: That just removes the error output but still errors out and finishes the script abruptly. It's a fine addition tho. Since I tried that again (and edited the file to circumvent problems like pseudo-selectors and propietary prefixes) I still get errors: `AttributeError: 'CSSTerminalFunction' object has no attribute 'lower' *** ERRORS OCCURED` - that's a bug in python-pisa, for what I can see. Any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

[WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org) is a visual rendering engine for HTML and CSS that can export to PDF. It aims to support web standards for printing. WeasyPrint is free software made available under the BSD license.